# How to avoid double inhertince

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt

I am trying to devlop a qt application and I have decided to make an abstract class named window that inherts from QWidget each window, diaoluge will inhert from her, and will include the basic proprties that window should have. Right now one of the classes that inherts from window also inhert from QMainWindow. My problam is that both QMainWindow and window  inherts from QWidget. That makes me think that my way of soltion is sub-optimal and there is a proper way to do the genraliztion I try to do, any advice will be welcomed.

Heres the code for refrence (delted unimportent parts) with the double inhertince:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget , ):
    _metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, win_name):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.name = win_name
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self, ):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.name)

        self.show()


class Main_Window(QtGui.QMainWindow,  Window):

    def __init__(self, win_name):
        super(Main_Window, self).__init__(win_name)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self, ):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('chk')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        super(Main_Window, self).initUI()
```

Comment: It seems fine, Python is made to handle those kind diamond shaped inheritance diagram uambiguously.

Comment: Do you think it`s an evidence to a design flow with my basic conecpt or are things like that fine ? @OlivierMelançon

Comment: I'm not sure of everything you want to accomplish, but adding methods from two different class can perfectly be done with multiple inheritance. And as I said, Python is made to handle those case unambiguously, so if you know what you are doing and understand method resolution order correctly, this is fine.

Comment: @hjsv41 
Main_Window inherits from QMainWindow, QMainWindow inherits from QWidget, so I do not understand the reason for creating the Window class

Comment: @eyllanesc I deleted some parts of the code to make it simpler. The reason for creating the Window class is to set some basic functions that will run on every widgets. The thing is that in order to inhert from the QMainWindow I need to inhrent once again from the Qwidget.

Comment: @hjsv41 
For example tell me a task that you want to implement in Window?

Comment: @eyllanesc center any widget, setting  colours for that widget, and maybe more that I havn`t thought about, its my first time working with qt so I am just trying things for now.

Comment: @hjsv41 I just tried and it is not necessary for Window to inherit from QWidget, look at my example: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/2830d916daf329f9d28af92fa3aeda0e,  is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Another option instead using inheritance would be using [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), here's a little example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


class GuiBuilder():
    def __init__(self, widget, name):
        self.widget = widget
        self.name = name
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.widget.setWindowTitle(self.name)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()

        self.gui_builder = GuiBuilder(self, name)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('chk')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.gui_builder.init_ui()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    for title in ["window1", "window2", "window3"]:
        ex = MainWindow(title)
        ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see I've refactored a bit your posted code, changed Window by GuiBuilder, Pep8 style, ... Of course, the above example doesn't make too much sense and you'd just use this approach if there was a good reason for it. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)